# How to move data from H2 Database(InMemory DB) to actual Database over JDBC Adapter?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, h2

I am using H2 database as a inmemory database for my java webapplication and I want to push the data into the actual database in background over JDBC.

One solution i found over is to use ThreadPoolExecutor and scheduling some threads. Is this the best option or do we have any alternate solutions?

Any Help is appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [Talend Data Integration Free Tool](https://www.talend.com/download/talend-open-studio/#t4). It allows you to

- transfer Data from one source to another
- crate a jar which you can include in your project

With the included JAR you can call there the create Job which will transfer the Data from your in Memory DB to the source DB.

Comment: Thanks for answer!! But i am looking for some code(Java) approach for the problem.